# Scanner class working only for 1 number

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am learning java and cannot figure it out that why the scanner class is working only for the number 1 integer and not for another number in my java code.For example if i take response as 2 from the user, it do not show anything.
I think i made the PlaceOrder and SellItem method perfectly but taking input as 2 or 3 or 4 from the user doesn't show any results. I made a PlaceOrder method in the Item class and called that method though input of the user as 2. Though pressing 2 at the time of input, it do not show the desired result.

**Main class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ItemTest{

public static void main(String [] args) {

    Item product = new Item("Wrench",15,15%10+15,"Craftsmen Tool",20,5,7);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a Action");
    System.out.println("1:Show Item \n" + "2.Sell an Item\n" + "3.Place an Order \n" + "4.Quit");

    if (scan.nextInt()==1) {

        System.out.println(product.toString());
    }
    if (scan.nextInt()==2) {

        System.out.println(product.SellItem());
    }
    if (scan.nextInt()==3) {

        System.out.println(product.PlaceOrder());
    }
    if (scan.nextInt()==4) {

        System.out.println("Thankyou for your visit");
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem here is, when u are entering value first time, it will check with first _scan.nextInt()_, and second time second _scan.nextInt()_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try and change this:

```
if (scan.nextInt()==1) {

    System.out.println(product.toString());
}

if (scan.nextInt()==2) {

    System.out.println(product.SellItem());
}
if (scan.nextInt()==3) {

    System.out.println(product.PlaceOrder());
}
if (scan.nextInt()==4) {

    System.out.println("Thankyou for your visit");
}
```

to

```
int choice = scan.nextInt();
if ( choice ==1) {

    System.out.println(product.toString());
} else if ( choice ==2) {

    System.out.println(product.SellItem());
} else if (choice==3) {

    System.out.println(product.PlaceOrder());
} else if (choice==4) {

    System.out.println("Thankyou for your visit");
}
```

otherwise, each if expects/waits for another input.

Comment: Thanks @Stultuske !

Comment: or u can use _switch statement_, if u use don't forget the **break**